# Update component from iframe

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

There are a `<p:inputText>` and a `<p:commandButton>`. I want to click the button to open a dialog with a table. When I select one row and press OK, I would like set the value of the selected row in the `<p:inputText>`.

In the dialog, I use an `<iframe>` and call a JS function to set the `src` of `<iframe>` and show the dialog. But I have no idea to update the `<p:inputText>` from an `<iframe>`.

Main page:

```
<h:form id="dialogForm">
  <p:inputText id="tarText" value="" />
  <p:commandButton value="master file" oncomplete="showDialog('#{request.contextPath}')" />
  <p:dialog widgetVar="lookupDialog" header="Lookup">
    <iframe id="myiframe"></iframe>

</h:form>
```

JS:

```
function showDialog(contextPath) {
    var myiframe = document.getElementById("myiframe");
    myiframe.src = contextPath + "/pages/lookup.xhtml";
    lookupDialog.show();
}
```

Edit----
@BalusC but how can I refresh a special area of this page by pressing a button? The more important thing is, the different button pressed, the different content shown out. And I don't wanna refresh the page sync.

Comment: i don't want to use a backing bean with sessionscope for this case

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you're using an `iframe` for this instead of server-side includes like `ui:include`?

Comment: @BalusC i want upload a image to show u, but seems not enough score

Comment: @BalusC i try to explan it...left tree menu and center iframe for the main page.I don't want refresh whole page when click the tree node.I could only think of this way to use iframe.